# what is my image source URL on docker hub for import ACR

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub

I have 2 images on Docker Hub. 
 What's my source URLs for images on Docker Hub? 
 I need to import image to ACR but I couldn't find my **source URLs**.

My images on Docker Hub. for example;  
- mocdoc/myapplicationrepo:driver-ui  
- mocdoc/myapplicationrepo:driver-api

what is my **image_source_url on Docker Hub?** command below;

Here my code for importing to ACR

```
az acr import –name myapp –source <image_source_url> –image <image_name>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Import from Docker Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images#import-from-docker-hub):

> For example, use the az acr import command to import the
> multi-architecture hello-world:latest image from Docker Hub to a
> registry named myregistry. Because hello-world is an official image
> from Docker Hub, this image is in the default library repository.
> **Include the repository name and optionally a tag in the value of the
> --source image parameter.** (You can optionally identify an image by its manifest digest instead of by tag, which guarantees a particular
> version of an image.)

```
az acr import \
  --name myregistry \
  --source docker.io/library/hello-world:latest \
  --image hello-world:latest
```

From [az acr import examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_import-examples):

> Import an image from a public repository on Docker Hub. The image uses
> the specified repository and tag names.

```
az acr import -n MyRegistry --source docker.io/library/hello-world:latest -t targetrepository:targettag
```

> Import an image from a private repository using its username and
> password. This also applies to registries outside Azure.

```
az acr import -n MyRegistry --source myprivateregistry.azurecr.io/hello-world:latest -u username -p password
```

In addition you can find  more information in [Unable to Import public Docker image](https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/476) dockerhub issue:

Answer on your question depends on few factors, e.g if it official image, public/private repository and presence of authentication.

```
To summarize:

--source docker.io/library/python creates a "library/python" repository at the ACR end.
--source docker.io/python fails with same error as "docker.io/library/axoniq/axonserver:latest" -> authentication required
--source docker.io/library/hello-world:latest creates a "hello-world" repository at the ACR end (leaving out "library/").
--source docker.io/library/axoniq/axonserver:latest fails
--source docker.io/axoniq/axonserver:latest works
```

If the image is in the library repository (https://hub.docker.com/u/library) then library is needed. If you have your own repository, then `library` is not needed..

I would say your version is

`az acr import --source docker.io/mocdoc/myapplicationrepo:driver-ui` , but you need to test according what you currently have.

Comment: If there is an update to the image on DockerHub will this auto sync that image to ACR?